# how to setdate on edit textview after being returned from datepicker

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-datepicker

I am using third party datepicker library in my android project. the link to this library is

I am opening this date picker when a button in my fragment is clicked. I have placed all dependencies of this datepicker library but when I try to access edittextview in onDateSet method of interface it shows me null pointer exception and don't let me access this edittextview

Following is the code of my fragment from where i open datepicker when button is pressed

```
package com.example.anonymous.ghar_ka_khana;

import android.content.Context;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;   
import com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog;
import com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog;

public class Selling_item_detail extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";  
    EditText timetext;
    EditText datetext;
    int hours;
    View v;               
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;   
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;    
    public Selling_item_detail() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Selling_item_detail newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Selling_item_detail fragment = new Selling_item_detail();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_selling_item_detail, container, false);
        /*timetext = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        datetext = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.date);*/           
        ImageButton calendarbutton =(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.dateButton);
        calendarbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        new Selling_item_detail(),
                        now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                );
                dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
            }
        });  
        ImageButton timebutton =(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.timeButton);
        timebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                TimePickerDialog dpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        new Selling_item_detail(),
                        now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                        now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                        now.isLenient()
                );
                dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
            }
        });

        return  v;
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()+ " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {          
        hours=year;
        timetext = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        datetext = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        Log.i("timecontext",timetext+"");
        Log.i("datecontext",datetext+"");
        Log.i("tareekh",dayOfMonth+"-"+monthOfYear+"-"+year);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)
    {
      //  timetext.setText(hourOfDay+":"+second+":"+minute);
        Log.i("waqt",hourOfDay+":"+second+":"+minute);
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

XML file of this fragment is following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="24dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            >

            <com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.view.BezelImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/header"
                android:id="@+id/seelingfoodimage"/>

            <com.scalified.fab.ActionButton
                android:id="@+id/cambutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                fab:button_color="#ffffff"
                fab:button_colorPressed="#FF0000"
                fab:image="@drawable/cam"
                fab:image_size="34dp" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
            app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
            app:mtf_image="@drawable/food"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/foodname"
                android:hint="Foodname"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
                app:mtf_image="@drawable/calendar"
                app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:hint="Selling Location"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/dateButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
            app:mtf_image="@drawable/calendar"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="Date"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField-->


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
                app:mtf_image="@drawable/time"
                app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:hint="Selling Location"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/timeButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/time"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:mtf_image="@drawable/time"
            app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mail"
                android:hint="Time"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField-->

        <com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:mtf_image="@drawable/plate"
            app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/plate"
                android:hint="Number Of Plates"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>



        <com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:mtf_image="@drawable/money"
            app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/money"
                android:hint="Price Per Plate"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
            app:mtf_image="@drawable/location"
            app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:hint="Selling Location"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mapButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/map"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/ok"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_selector" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_selector" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<!--ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#a1000000"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.anonymous.ghar_ka_khana.Selling_item_detail">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/frame"
         >
        <com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.view.BezelImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/header"
         android:id="@+id/seelingfoodimage"/>

        <com.scalified.fab.ActionButton
            android:id="@+id/cambutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            fab:button_color="#ffffff"
            fab:button_colorPressed="#FF0000"
            fab:image="@drawable/cam"
            fab:image_size="34dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frame"
        app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
        app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
        app:mtf_image="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        app:mtf_hasFocus="true"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/foodname"
            android:hint="Foodname"
            android:text="food"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField-->

    <!--com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foodnames"
        android:id="@+id/dates"
        app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
        app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
        app:mtf_image="@drawable/calendar"
        app:mtf_hasFocus="true"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:hint="Foodname"
            android:text="food"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>

    <com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dates"
        android:id="@+id/times"
        app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
        app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
        app:mtf_image="@drawable/time"
        app:mtf_hasFocus="true"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:hint="Foodname"
            android:text="food"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>

    <com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/times"
        android:id="@+id/plates"
        app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
        app:mtf_labelColor="#666"
        app:mtf_image="@drawable/plate"
        app:mtf_hasFocus="true"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/plate"
            android:hint="Foodname"
            android:text="food"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView-->
```

Comment: I can't see where you are setting your date to your edittext... and the second thing is are you sure you are getting the date/time from datepicker ?

Comment: when my codes try to fetch refrences of both edittextview in these two lines in OnDateSet  timetext = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        datetext = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.date); . it throws null pointer exception . yes i ahve donr Log.i() the date/time from datepicker . it shows date and time . but throws exception when tries to fetch refrence of edittextview

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way. Because view you pass to eddittext is of dialogPicker not of fragment. That's why it is giving you the null pointer exception.

Comment: @umair how can you say that the view i ma passing to edittextview is of dialogue picker

Comment: Sorry i didn't saw that the view you are passing is declared globally. but it is good that you should declare your widgets in onCreateView here.

Comment: i also tried by creating in oncreateview but still error

Comment: can you check if you are getting dates in your log ? if yes then i think you are not setting proper id's to your edittext.

Comment: yes I am getting date and time in log and ids are ids also set properly

Answer (score 1):

I am putting my custom code for open `date picker` and set the date on text:

```
public static void showDatePicker(Context context, final AppCompatEditText editText) {
    // Get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    editText.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: my brother i  am using third party library and it has its own method for opening datepicker.link to this library is this https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: trying to use getChildFragmentManager() when initializing time or date picker
and if this not works then check is it returning to activity or fragment?

Comment: @Johonsmuthio why you are using library where as this answer is a simple solution to open dialog. just add this method call to button click

Comment: I am using the library because there are few properties in that library which I want in my project that's why I am using that library

Answer (score 0):

Declare your eddittext in `OnCreateView()` of fragment. like this:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_selling_item_detail, container, false);
    timetext = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.time);
    datetext = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.date);
    return v;
}
```

Take a global string that will save your date and time.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma");
String date = mMonth+1 + "/" + mDay + "/" + mYear + " : " + simpleDateFormat.format(time);
```

And then set your date/time to your eddittext in those overrided methods.

```
 timetext.setText(date);
```